# Recognition of a Keyword in a Sentence Using Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, speech-recognition

I'm a first time Kinect user looking to program an application that would respond when it hears a particular keyword (or keyphrase) in a sentence. For example, if the phrase was "that way", I would like Kinect to accept as matching on the following sentences:

- "Is it **this way**?"
- "Should I go **this way**?"
- "Is **this way** correct?"

...and so on.

Looking around online at documentation, I get the impression that Kinect can only achieve recognition for an utterance via the `Grammar` class - essentially, I would have to be aware of all utterances which contain those keywords/phrases before writing this application, rather than being able to just match keywords/phrases within a larger, unknown utterance.

Is this accurate? Or is there a way to do this with a Kinect?

Comment: You might be interested in the following answer to understand the difference between speech recognition implemented in Kinect and keyword spotting http://stackoverflow.com/a/12823055/432021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes - your impression is correct.

The first thing to point out is the Kinect is really just a microphone for speech.  It does nothing for the speech processing, so you are not bound to any particular libraries if you find a package that does better for your needs.

When using Microsoft Speech you have to be a little more clear on what you want to be matching.  Looking for individual words (e.g., "Mary" and "Lamb") and hoping it will pick up phrases (e.g., "Mary had a little lamb") will prove difficult.  Here are two links that will give you a good idea of what is possible with Microsoft Speech:

- [Microsoft Speech Platform Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd266409.aspx)
- [Speech Recognition Grammar Specification Version 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/)

The second link is a very good one that will show you how you can tailor the grammar lookups in a way that will give you a better chance of finding what you are looking for.  For example, adding in optional words and alternative phrases.  For more complex grammar, a SRGS formatted file is really the way to go (in my opinion) over code.

But all hope is not lost.  Microsoft Speech offers a few gems that may help you out...

**Confidence Level** - you can tell the engine to be a little more lenient with the vocabulary.  If you are just looking for 2 words in a 4-5 word phrase, this may work out very well for you!  Millage various depending on the application, so I can't say for sure it will work for your needs... but it might help.

**Speech Hypothesized** - in addition to the Speech Recognized event, Microsoft Speech has a Hypothesized event.  It is a little looser and can catch items that are part of a larger phrase.  Again, millage always various so I can't say for sure this will be the solution
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.speechhypothesized.aspx

Last bit, you can look into packages like Dragon Natural Speaking.  Companies like Dragon have put a lot of effort into creating packages that allow people to speak more naturally and without learning a new set of phrases.

Comment: Thank you for all of this information. I've had some time to play with it over the weekend, and - using your suggestions - I think Kinect will suffice for what I'm looking for. Your post is a great resource for those who it won't work for though.

Comment: @Evil Closet Monkey is there some hack using BabbleTimeout, EndSilenceTimeout, ... to ease matching words in a sentence ? Do you have a clever use example of Speech Hypothesized ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeEncausse - sorry, I've not used `BabbleTimeout` or `EndSilenceTimeout` before.  I've nothing using `SpeechHypothesized` that is beyond just taking advantage catching a phrase and either acting on it, or asking the user to verify they said that and reply "yes" or "no".